# Cant scroll an ListView that contains an Expander and an ItemControl WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, scroll, expander

So I am trying to make a little shopping list app for the family, but I cant figure out what I am doing wrong. When I have a list of Items that goes off the screen when you expand the expanders, the ListBox does not allow me to scroll.

The Code is:

```
<StackPanel>
        <ListView Name="ListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Add" Click="AddClick" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Edit" Click="EditClick" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="DeleteClick" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Expander Header="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Ingredients, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="False">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <template:IngredientsTemplate IsEnabled="False"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Expander>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Remove the `StackPanel`. Why do you event need a `Panel` just to wrap a `ListView`?

Comment: I will be expanding it once I have this working and I will require it. However for the problem I am having removing it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Then you probably have some other `StackPanel` involved as well. You should post all of your markup.

Comment: I did. It was on the main window. The very first element was causing it. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the parent StackPanel. WPF layout controls work by first querying their children to determine how much space is needed, then applying the layout logic, then telling each child how much space they've actually been allocated. During the layout process that StackPanel is asking the ListView how much space it wants, to which the ListView responds with all the space it needs to display all the elements it has, and so the StackPanel sets its own size to encompass all that required space.

To fix this you're going to have to replace that StackPanel with something like a Grid (say) and/or re-think how you do your layout.

Comment: I do get a horizontal scrollbar that seems to belong to the outer list view when I open an expander. Also when I open the expanders the Listview does expand it's size to accommodate the expanders contents. When I use a grid it behaves the exact same.

Comment: This fixed it. The very first element was a stackpanel that was causing the listview to take up all the room.